# Very long name of Section reflects badly in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking

I have too long name of Section that reflects badly in TOC.

Name of section doesn't have spaces in its name.

I can not know how pledge it to move part of name to the next line automatically.

(Idea to split name manually is bad).

[image]

---

---

---

```
 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \part{New Part}
 \chapter{Name of the Chapter}

%Can not fit on the page, and can not be divided automatically
 \section{This\_Is\_very\_Long\_Name\_of\_Section\_That\_Can\_Not\_Fit\_On\_Page\_And\_Push\_Out\_Of\_The\_Page\_Field}
 \section{This\_Is\_very\_Long\_Name\_of\_Section \ That\_Have\_Spaces On\_Its Name \ And\_Will\_Be Bring\_On\_The\_Next\_Line}

 \end{document}
```

Also, name of section creates automatically, and I previously cannot know how long will be it.

Comment: This surely needs a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` and containing only the section and the table of contents, and all packages that influence their appearance. One of the reasons is that I don't understand how the section title fits in the page, when the TOC line does not (since TOC line is in a smaller font).

Comment: Try `\section{\url{very_long_name}}`. Requires `url` package. I'm not sure if `\url` is a fragile macro, in this case this will not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\_\protect\linebreak[0]` instead of `\_` then it will allow (but not encourage) breaking after the `_`

---

Or if you want to allow the lines to fall short at the breaks,

```
\def\myunderscore{\_\nobreak\hfil\protect\penalty0\hfilneg}
\tableofcontents

\section{abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz\myunderscore abcxyz}
```

Comment: You could also introduce possible linebreak points using the package `babel` and the command `"-`.

Comment: Note if you got `[0]` in the output from the first version, it would appear that there is a mistake in your document somewhere.